# How to combine rows if the first group by clause is satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple query that pulls sets by employee for each location.

Let's say I have the following data:

```
Username   Store_number   Invoice_amt
TJ1          1                5
TJ1          1                5
TJ1          2                5
RB2          3                5
RB2          3                5
DD1          4                5
DD1          4                5
```

I have a query:

```
Select username, Sum(invoice_amt) as Total, Store_number
```

I'll have the following output:

```
username    Total      store_number
TJ1          10          1
TJ1          5           2
RB2          10          3
DD1          10          4
```

What i'm looking to do - Is combine the usernames first, then split it out by store number - Is there a way for my output to be:

```
username    Total      store_number
TJ1          15          1
RB2          10          3
DD1          10          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that you probably don't want the minimum store.  You probably want the most common value for store.  If so:

```
select username, amount,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then store end) as most_common_store
from (select username, store, sum(invoice_amount) as amount,
             row_number() over (partition by username order by sum(invoice_amount) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by username, store
     ) us
group by username;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just take the `min(store_number)`

```
select 
    username
  , Sum(invoice_amt) as Total
  , min(store_number) as Store_number
from t
group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be your query if I understood your question right.

```
Select 
username,
sum(invoice_amt) as Total,
Min(store_number) as store_number
from Table!
Group By UserName
```